# User claims in custom claim provider

Tags: claims-based-auth, claims, claim-provider

I have a custom claims provider and now I got this new requirement to augment some new claims based on claims which user already has.

How can I get user claims which are already augmented (eg. those coming from ADFS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get claims through below code:

```
        var claimsPrincipal = Page.User as IClaimsPrincipal;
        if (claimsPrincipal != null)
        {
            IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (IClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
            var userClaims = claimsIdentity.Claims;
        }
```

But if you want to add the claim at the time of augmentation, then probably following link guide you more.

[How to Get All User Claims at Claims Augmentation Time in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2011/03/29/how-to-get-all-user-claims-at-claims-augmentation-time-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Make sure you add a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll which comes with Windows Identity Foundation

Comment: Link looks promising. I'll check that and get back with result.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (link to Steve Peshka's Blog)!

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the link,

http://ldapcp.codeplex.com/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.